# Transfer files via USB 3 bridge

Tags: networking, usb, network-bridge

I want to transfer files between 2 machines that run both Ubuntu 20.04. I have an ethernet connection via cross-over patch using samba, but the speeds are horrible. I want to test a USB connection between both and for that I bought an USB 3 bridge cable, something like this: https://www.amazon.com/usb-bridge-cable/s?k=usb+bridge+cable. I managed to have a connection between the 2, but my question right now is: how do I actually transfer files between them? Is there a program or commands that I can use in terminal? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I actually use FTP a lot for this sort of thing. On your network, you can just use .local and access stuff. For example, this is "kgiii-desktop" and I can access it over the network as "kgiii-desktop.local". Each computer is connected to the same router so on the same network. I set up FTP on both of 'em and transfer files back and forth all the time. It's fast enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (and many other Linux distributions) will generally treat these sorts of things as network devices. You should be able to use `scp` or similar functions to move data between the systems. Use something like `ifconfig` to get the IP addresses associated with the USB bridge, and you should be good.